# android Universal ImageLoader Check if image is loaded

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal ImageLoader for the loading images using URL to imageview in my recyclerview.Is there a code to check if the image is loaded.Below is the onBindViewHolder method of recyclerview   where I loaded images to imageview

Code:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        DisplayImageOptions options=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ktdclogonew)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ktdclogonew).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(new Images().getIm(i), viewHolder.imageView, options);
        viewHolder.textView1.setText(hoteldata[i].getHotel());
        viewHolder.textView2.setText(hoteldata[i].getPlace());



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(new Images().getIm(i), viewHolder.imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
@Override
public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
    // When loading of image starts
}
@Override
public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
    // When loading of image is failed
}
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    // When loading of image is completed
}
@Override
public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
    // When loading of image is cancelled by user.
}
});
```

Reference : [Universal Image Loader Documentation](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#complete)